# NSSegmentedControl (subclass NSSegmentCell) Text Color

Tags: cocoa, subclass, textcolor, nssegmentedcontrol

I create a `NSSegmentedControl` as multiple badge for a Sourcelist. The first segment has a green Color and shows a count of items which matched different rules. The second segment has a red color and counts unmatched rules. The `NSSegmentedControl` is disable so that the user cant click it. The Text color is gray because its disable.

How can I change the the Text color?
I have tried to set the color in the NSSegmentCell subclass with the method "setAttributedStringValue:" but it does not work.

```
[self setAttributedStringValue:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this info will be of any help to you anymore, but if you're still on the lookout for answers …

To set an attributed string's text color, you have to add an `NSColor` object to the attributed string's attribute dictionary with the key, `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`. I'll show you a few ways I know how to do it.

**Creating an Attributed String from an `NSString` Object:**

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[NSColor redColor]};
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"
                                                              attributes:attrs];
```

**From an Existing `NSAttributedString` Object:**

```
NSMutableAttributedString *tempAttributedString = anExistingAttributedString.mutableCopy;
[tempAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                             value:[NSColor redColor] 
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, tempAttributedString.length)];
anExistingAttributedString = tempAttributedString;
```

So in a subclass, you'll probably want to intercept the value passed to `-setAttributedStringValue:` like so:

```
- (void)setAttributedStringValue:(NSAttributedString *)attributedStringValue
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *temp = attributedStringValue.mutableCopy;
    [temp addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName 
                 value:[NSColor redColor] 
                 range:NSMakeRange(0, temp.length)];
    [super setAttributedStringValue:temp];
}
```

That may or may not be the best way of handling things, but since there's so little information out there on subclassing, it seems like a good bet to me. If you know all of this already, I apologize for the long-winded answer. If you don't, hopefully this helps! Good luck.

Comment: That doesn't work for NSSegmentControl (or NSSegmentCell) probable because NSSegmentControl doesn't a single string value but string values for each segment and there is a setLabel:forSegment: there is no version that takes an NSAttributedString.